# Linking to NuGet from GitHub

Tags: github, nuget

I have a repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/) and I've created a corresponding packing on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/). I would like to link to the NuGet package from my GitHub README file.

After modifying some text I found on other repositories, I came up with the following:

```
[![NuGet version (SoftCircuits.Silk)](https://img.shields.io/nuget/v/SoftCircuits.Silk.svg?style=flat-square)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SoftCircuits.Silk/)
```

In a GitHub MD file (and here), this produces the following link:

[image: NuGet version (SoftCircuits.Silk)]

That seems good but I'd like to find more about this. After Googling for quite a while, I haven't been able to find where these type of links are documented. Do I have the correct usage? Are there other options I might want to take advantage of? And so on?

Is there a reference for these type of links somewhere?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your link comes from the service `shields.io`, which offers badge images for all sorts of services and all sorts of info. The reason you had a hard time finding documentation is probably because badges aren't GitHub specific, that's just one place you can use them. So if you search for "nuget badge" instead of "nuget github", you'll find the `shields.io` site is the first result.

As for documentation, it's all at [shields.io](https://shields.io/). Click "Version" and scroll down to see the specific NuGet badge that you're using. There are badges for a lot of other information (size, # of downloads, etc) there, too.

Comment: Thanks. I actually ran across that page. But the home page is just a list rather than a description of what they are doing. I can't imagine anyone writing a website like that but it happens.

Comment: The documentation is a bit split up. If you scroll down past that list on the home page, it gives you info on all the different badge options: label, colors, etc. The lists are then information for all the supported services. So you take the information, form say, `Version -> NuGet`, and use it to build a URL per the configuration options on the home page.